# OpenCV is slow to read video in multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I have a problem that with multithreading opencv is slow to read video, outputs 2 FPS, but computer resources are all free. It is used only:

CPU (i7 3.6GHz): 1-2%, 98% free

RAM: 1GB / 64GB

Multiprocessing is not suitable (or maybe I'm not using it correctly), because in the future will be the recognition of objects and it naturally gives out of memory.

I thought that the problem in the video codec h264 (although again, resources are free), but I still tried other codecs, all the same.

Please tell me what the problem may be and what are the options for solving it?

```
import cv2
import time
from threading import Thread,Semaphore


def start(i):
    video_path = "backups/3/2/2023-06-18_20-27-50.mp4"
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
    while cap.isOpened():
        success, frame = cap.read()     
        if success:
            new_time = time.time() 
            elapsed_time  = new_time - prev_time

            if i == 14:
                fps = int(1/elapsed_time )
                cv2.putText(frame, str(int(fps)), (7, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (100, 255, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.imshow("Inference", cv2.resize(frame,(960,540)))
            
            prev_time = new_time
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
                break
        else:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    


threads = []
i = 0
while i < 15:
    t = Thread(target=start,args=(i,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
    i += 1
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: so you started 15 threads in parallel, all decoding the same video, and you wonder why stuff is crawling? besides that, running GUI (imshow, waitkey) from a thread is not recommended. for some GUI libraries, it's even an error.

Comment: Also be aware that opencv has its own parallel computing package. On a multi-application situation we observed that a huge threat-pool was generated and most of the time, the cpu pushing threads to the background. Pleass try to set opencv setNumThreads (or similar) to 1 and test again.